# Indent of book TOC entries

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I have tried several of the examples of TOC formatting that I found in this forum, using the `titlesec` package and `\titlecontents{chapter}` but I cannot get my book TOC chapter entries to indent correctly as in
[image]

An excerpt of the code I am using is

```
\documentclass{book} 
% It MUST be compiled with LuaLaTex
%PAGES
\usepackage[
    vcentering, 
    hcentering, 
    inner=16mm,
    outer=16mm,
    top=22.0mm, 
    bottom=15.0mm,
    headsep=9.3mm,
    headheight=5mm,
%   showframe
    ]
    {geometry} % Extended page layout customization

\geometry{papersize={189mm,246mm}} % Possible dimensions of textbook pages
%\usepackage[cross,a4,center]{crop} %Package to print on A4 with crop signs. 
\usepackage{multicol}% handling of multicolumn in documents
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}%enables table of contents with multiple columns
    \renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}% Set two columns for the table of contents
\usepackage{emptypage} % suppresses page numbers and headings on empty pages
\usepackage{xcolor}[2007/01/21] % Driver-independent color extensions

%FONTS
\usepackage{fontspec}%LuaLaTex fonts
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,ItalicFont={Apollo MT Std Italic}]{Apollo MT}
\usepackage{titletoc,xpatch}%
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}% An in­ter­face to sec­tion­ing com­mands for se­lec­tion from var­i­ous ti­tle styles.

%Font families
\newfontfamily\Avenir{Avenir}
\newfontfamily\AvenirLight{Avenir Light}
\newfontfamily\AvenirHeavy{Avenir Heavy}


%Chapters in TOC 
\newcommand{\chaptertocfont}        {\fontsize{10}{12}\color{red}\AvenirHeavy}
\newcommand{\chaptertocpagefont}        {\fontsize{10}{12}\color{red}\AvenirHeavy}

\titlecontents{chapter}% section-type
    [0em]% left
    {\vspace*{0.6cm}}% above code
    {\chaptertocfont\thecontentslabel\quad}% numbered-entry format
    {}% numberless-entry format
    {\hfill\chaptertocpagefont\contentspage}[]% filler-page format  

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Energy Conversion Systems}

\chapter{Thermodynamic Properties of Multicomponent Fluids}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have your fonts. But maybe you want

```
\titlecontents{chapter}% section-type
    [1.5em]% <- changed
    {\vspace*{0.6cm}}
    {\chaptertocfont\contentslabel{1.5em}}% <- changed
    {\hspace*{-1.5em}}% <- changed
    {\hfill\chaptertocpagefont\contentspage}[]
```

---

Here is another suggestion using package `tocbasic` instead `titletoc`. Then you can remove package `multitoc` and it is possible to avoid the hyphenation of the long chapter title in TOC:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
  vcentering, 
  hcentering, 
  inner=16mm,
  outer=16mm,
  top=22.0mm, 
  bottom=15.0mm,
  headsep=9.3mm,
  headheight=5mm,
%  showframe
]{geometry} % Extended page layout customization
\geometry{papersize={189mm,246mm}} % Possible dimensions of textbook pages

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{multicol}% handling of multicolumn in documents

\usepackage{tikz} % loads also xcolor, graphicx, ...
\definecolor{BlueGreen}{RGB}{7,116,159}
\definecolor{LightBlue}{RGB}{185,229,251}
\definecolor{LightGreen}{RGB}{203,231,211}

\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[\jobname]{toc}
\renewcommand*\tableofcontents{\listoftoc[\contentsname]{toc}}
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=.6cm plus 1pt,
  entryformat=\chaptertocfont,
  pagenumberformat=\chaptertocpagefont,
  raggedentrytext=true
]{tocline}{chapter}
\newcommand*{\chaptertocfont}[1]{\normalsize\bfseries\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\chaptertocpagefont}[1]{\chaptertocfont{#1}}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Energy Conversion Systems}
\lipsum
\chapter{Thermodynamic Properties of Multicomponent Fluids}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you also know how I can avoid that the long chapter name is hyphened in the TOC?